# access methods from plain code files and call it in main class (like php include)

Tags: c#, .net

This was a general question asked by a colleague of mine....

> Is it possible to "outsource" code, and then call it in the main class (e.g. Form1.cs)?

This originates from the fact that he wants to organize his amount of code better than with regions, in the main class.

My first thought was - of course it is! 
Use `static Extentions`, reference it to the main class, and call it through `this.Method()`.

But he meant something like the "include" pattern in PHP....

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> he wants to organize his amount of code better than with regions, in the main class.

You can use [partial classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to split the implementation of a single class into multiple (and perhaps more manageable) source files.

In `File1.cs`:

```
public partial class MyClass {

  public void F() { ... }

}
```

In `File2.cs`:

```
public partial class MyClass {

  public void G() { ... }

}
```

`MyClass` now has two methods, `F` and `G`.

Answer (score 2):

You can externalize using partial classes or decouple it using c# assembly (dll).